# curl file[] equivalent

Tags: curl

if in the html form using parametrs like `file[]` (with `"[]"`) what is equivalent in curl?
i tried `curl -F "file[]=@C:\1.png"` but it doest'n work.

Comment: Could you please describe the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: i'm trying to solve multiple file upload. Files send to the php script by file[]. I can't show you php code because i don't have it, sorry.